# How do I configure the recurring node checkout payment?

Tags: 7, commerce

In the past years, I use commerce node checkout to published a node when the user checkout completed. Now I want to automatically, charge user when their node published expired.

How can I link the node to the recurring product, so the recurring payment happen when the node expire every month?

Comment: There's  a two type of recurring entities, 'Product' and 'Order'.  I think, the 'Order' entity type can be use to recurring the node checkout order...Investigating continue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.  I've read the file "README.txt" and found that any product type can be a recurring product.

Now I configured my existing product type to add the fields, required by recurring payment.  So, now when I checkout, it does create a recurring entities for this order.  Hope it will help someone.